# insertRowsAtIndexPaths jumps with custom cell UITableView and UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am dynamically adding cells to my UITableView when the user scrolls down. It is working perfectly.

The issue I am having is that after the new rows are added the tableview jumps. I need it to stay in place and the new rows to be added to the bottom which I thought would have been done by default. I'm not sure if I am doing something really wrong here or if this is a bug when using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

There is a white flash before the new cells are rendered.

My code is

```
 func offerNotification(hasError : Bool?, errorDescription : String?, isCategory : String?, isComplete : Bool, isPagination : Bool, offerUpdate : NSMutableArray?){
    //Append New & Old Array
    let count = self.offersArray.count - 1
    self.offersArray.addObjectsFromArray(offerUpdate! as [AnyObject])

    //Create Array of Indexpaths
    var indexpaths : Array<NSIndexPath> = []
     for (index, _) in offerUpdate!.enumerate() {
        let nspath = NSIndexPath(forRow: count + index, inSection: 0)
        indexpaths.append(nspath)
    }

    //Add to Table
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexpaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Anyone experienced this?

A test project showing this issue is here https://github.com/oddpanda/Endless-Scrolling-Test

Comment: Where is the `beginUpdates` method called?

Comment: In a standard function when it is detected that the `uitableview` is at the bottom `func offerNotification(hasError : Bool?, errorDescription : String?, isCategory : String?, isComplete : Bool, isPagination : Bool, offerUpdate : NSMutableArray?){` Will add my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same issue I had.

I had `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` in my delegate method which when removed 
fixed all my issues.

May be unique to my issue but hopefully it can help someone.